# Server failed to load resource (404) what do I do?

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I can't solve my server problem; could you help on this?

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="" id="rainbow">
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
        console.log('im trying to fetch a c# logo')
        fetch('download.png').then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
    </script>
```

Error message:

> im trying to fetch a c# logo
> fetch.html:44 Live reload enabled.
> download.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `404 error` belongs to the `4xx error` category and indicates an error on the client's side.

A 404 error occurs when a file cannot be found.

How can you fix this?

1. Check if the image is in the **same path** as your script / HTML file.
2. Check the name and extension of the image / file. Has a **typing error** crept in?